# How to Import an Oracle dump version 5.1 into 12c?

Tags: oracle, impdp

I have `.dmp` files exported as version 5.1 and I need to import them on an Oracle 12c. **I have no access to the original database to re-export** setting the VERSION parameter.

This is the error I get:

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39142: incompatible version number 5.1 in dump file "/media/sf_Data
/DUMP_MS/mydumfile.dmp"
```

What can I do?

Comment: By the way, this ORA-39142 error message may be wrong because the log of the export says the originating system was a version 12...

Comment: What version of 12c? 12.1 uses dump file sets of version 4.1. 12.2 uses dump file sets of version 5.1

Comment: you will probably have to import into an older version and then re export to your final version. contacting Oracle support might be an idea

Comment: I am using  Release 12.1.0.2.0 dump was generated on a 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: Isn't there a way to patch the dumpfiles?

Comment: You can also simply ask whoever did the export in 12.2 to redo it, this time specifying the VERSION=12.1 parameter. This is how you generate dump files that are downwards compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course Oracle did not make this information public, but if you can access MOS, then go ahead:

[Export/Import DataPump Parameter VERSION - Compatibility of Data Pump Between Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 553337.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=553337.1)

12.1 uses dump file sets of version 4.1. 12.2 uses dump file sets of version 5.1

You can not import a dump file created in 12.2 to 12.1, unless the VERSION parameter was specified to allow lower versions to import it.

You will need at least a 12.2 version database to import that dumpfile.